# CSS code structure feedback / optimization

Tags: html, css

Now that I'm done with the design of my website, i'm trying to optimize the css code (have used pieces of code provided by stackoverflow users, forums, my own code, etc). I've tried to clean it already but i'm sure there are still some room for improvement. Your feedback would be much appreciated! many thanks

CSS:

```
html, body, #contact-us {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    font: 12px 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}
* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
.clearfix {
    display: block;
}
p {
    font: 12px 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #000;
}
h1 {
    font: 24px 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    color: #0A4672;
}
h2 {
    font: 22px 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    color: #467FD9;
}
span.team-function {
    font: 12px 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    color: #467FD9;
}
span.activity-title {
    font: 22px 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color: #467FD9;
}
p.activity-footnote {
    font: 10px 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: left;
    color: #000;
}
/* Positionning the logo on top left side */
#logo {
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    top: 20px;
    left: 2%;
    font: 28px 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    z-index:1000;
}
/* End Logo */

/* Horizontal Menu, aligned on the right side */
#nav {
    right: 2%;
    list-style: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
#nav > li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    zoom: 1;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#nav a {
    font: 12px 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    float: left;
    top: 30px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 24px;
    color: #666;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: white;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    opacity: 0.8;
}
#nav a:hover {
    background: #dedede;
}
#nav .current a {
    background: #666;
    color: #ededed;
}
/* End Menu */


/* Page Presentation */
#presentation {
    height: 1300px;
    background: #afc9ff;
    background: url(../images/bg-24.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
#presentation-container {
    width:810px;
    padding-top: 15%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.presentation-highlights {
    text-align: justify;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-right:7px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
    font: 12px 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    width: 230px;
    Height:90px;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=85)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=95);
    opacity: 0.85; /* For IE8 and earlier */
    border: 1px dotted #666;
    background: #fff;
}
/* End Page presentation */


/* Page Equipe */
#team {
    height: 1300px;
    padding-top: 150px;
    background: #8aba56;
    background: url(../images/bg-23.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
#team-container {
    width:960px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=83)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=83);
    opacity: 0.83; /* For IE8 and earlier */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px dotted #666;
}
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#team-left {
    color:#000;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-top:20px;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#team-right {
    font:12px 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight:400;
    padding-left:25px;
    padding-top:24px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    color:#000;
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    text-align:justify;
}
.image-center {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-right: -15px;
}
/* Page Plan d'Activité */
#activity {
    height: 1300px;
    background: #8aba56;
    padding-top: 150px;
    background: url(../images/bg-22.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
#activity-container {
    width: 640px;
    font:12px 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight:400;
    text-align:justify;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font: 12px 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    color:#000;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding:25px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px dotted #666;
    background: #fff url(../images/norway-map.png) no-repeat right center;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=93)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=93);
    opacity: 0.93; /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
/* End Page Activity */

/* Page Source */
#source {
    height: 1300px;
    background: #8aba56;
    padding-top: 150px;
    background: url(../images/bg-28.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
#source-container {
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=93)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=93);
    opacity: 0.93; /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
.source-title-box {
    color: #000;
    background: #fff;
    width: 230px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top:10px;
    border: 1px dotted #666;
}
.source-title-box a {
    color:#467FD9;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 15px;
}
.source-title-box a:hover {
    background-color:#467FD9;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
#source-region, #source-oursource {
    font:12px 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight:400;
    text-align:justify;
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    padding:15px 20px 20px 20px;
    display:block;
    width: 510px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px dotted #666;
    line-height:1px;
}
#source-oursource {
    display:none;
}
#source-oursource p {
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
#source-region p {
    margin-bottom:5px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
/* Page Medias */
#medias {
    height: 1300px;
    background: #8aba56;
    padding-top: 150px;
    background: url(../images/bg-18.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
#medias-container {
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#medias-title-box {
    color: #000;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px dotted #666;
}
#medias-table-header {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    width: 490px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px dotted #666;
}
#medias-table-header-type, #medias-table-header-desc, #medias-table-header-lang {
    font: 22px 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    padding: 15px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#medias-table-header-desc {
    width: 200px;
}
#medias-table-header-lang {
    width: 85px;
}
.medias-table-content {
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    width: 490px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px dotted #666;
}
.medias-table-content-type, .medias-table-content-desc, .medias-table-content-lang {
    padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;
    background: #fff;
    text-align:center;
    color: #000;
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.medias-table-content-desc {
    font: 14px 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align:left;
    Vertical-align:middle;
}
.medias-table-content-desc a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
    Vertical-align:middle;
}
.medias-table-content-desc a:hover {
    color:#0A4672;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.medias-table-content-lang {
    width: 85px;
}
/* end page medias */

/* Page Contact */
#contact-us {
    background: #8aba56;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    background: url(../images/bg-26.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
#contact-box {
    text-align:center;
    font: 12px 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    width: 300px;
    Height:120px;
    padding:15px;
    /*margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;*/
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=85)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=95);
    opacity: 0.85; /* For IE8 and earlier */
    border: 1px dotted #666;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -80px;
    margin-left: -150px;
}
#contact-box p {
    font: 12px 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #000;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    margin-bottom:3px;
}
#contact-box h2 {
    font: 22px 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    color: #467FD9;
}
.highlightit img {
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity: 1;
    opacity: 1;
}
.highlightit:hover img {
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=100);
    -moz-opacity: 0.7;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
/* Section Footer with social icons on the left and address and flags on the right */
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #333;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 96%;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 30px 2%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
#social {
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: middle;
    left: 2%;
    color: #333;
}
.txtcentered {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -150px;
}
.fb_iframe_widget, iframe.twitter-share-button {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
span.languageselector {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px; /* same height as #social div */
    line-height: 20px; /* same as line-height */
}
/*contact form*/
#inline {
    display: none;
    width: 600px;
}
.txt {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #676767;
    width: 420px;
    font-family: Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px dotted #ccc;
    padding: 5px 9px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
}
.txtarea {
    display: block;
    -webkit-resize: none;
    -moz-resize: none;
    -webkit-resize: none;
    -moz-resize: none;
    resize: none;
    color: #676767;
    font-family: Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px dotted #ccc;
    padding: 5px 9px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
}
.txt:focus, .txtarea:focus {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #bababa;
    color: #444;
}
input.error, textarea.error {
    border-color: #973d3d;
    border-style: solid;
    background: #f0bebe;
    color: #a35959;
}
input.error:focus, textarea.error:focus {
    border-color: #973d3d;
    color: #a35959;
}
#send {
    color: #dee5f0;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 11px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    border: solid 1px #224983;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #1e4c99;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#2f52b7), to(#0e3a7d));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2f52b7, #0e3a7d);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2f52b7, #0e3a7d);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2f52b7, #0e3a7d);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2f52b7, #0e3a7d);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #2f52b7, #0e3a7d);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#2f52b7', endColorstr='#0e3a7d');
}
#send:hover {
    background: #183d80;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#284f9d), to(#0c2b6b));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #284f9d, #0c2b6b);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #284f9d, #0c2b6b);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #284f9d, #0c2b6b);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #284f9d, #0c2b6b);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #284f9d, #0c2b6b);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#284f9d', endColorstr='#0c2b6b');
}
#send:active {
    color: #8c9dc0;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0e387d), to(#2f55b7));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0e387d, #2f55b7);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0e387d, #2f55b7);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0e387d, #2f55b7);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0e387d, #2f55b7);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #0e387d, #2f55b7);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0e387d', endColorstr='#2f55b7');
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="."/>
<link href="../css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="../fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700,600,500,400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" /></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.queryloader2.js" type="text/javascript" /></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/scripts.js" /></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.0.6" /></script>
</head>
<body>
<!--[if lte IE 6]><script src="../js/ie6/warning.js"></script><script>window.onload=function(){e("js/ie6/")}</script><![endif]-->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div id="logo"><img src="../images/logo-khklhll-white.png" alt="" title="" /></div>
<ul id="nav">
  <li class="current"><a href="#presentation">Accueil</a></li>
  <li><a href="#activity">L'Entreprise</a></li>
  <li><a href="#team">L'équipe</a></li>
  <li><a href="#source">Notre Eau</a></li>
  <li><a href="#medias">Presse</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact-us">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="presentation">
  <div id="presentation-container">
    <h1>S.</h1>
    <h1>No</h1>
    <div class="presentation-highlights">
      <p><b>Eau </b></p>
      <p>S.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="presentation-highlights">
      <p><b>Ee</b></p>
      <p>Sle.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="presentation-highlights">
      <p><b>Ds</b></p>
      <p>Sts.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--END page1-->
<div id="activity">
  <div id="activity-container">
    <p><span class="activity-title">khklhll, naturlig mineralvann, ren natur</span></p>
    <br />
    <p>khklhll AS was2011.</p>
    <br />
    <p>A lot otors.</p>
    <br />
    <p>khklhll AS ha).</p>
    <br />
    <p>Ouryear.</p>
    <br />
    <p>Our pr12.</p>
    <br />
    <p class="activity-footnote"><i>* Legislation ers.</i></p>
  </div>
</div>
<!--END page2-->
<div id="team">
  <div id="team-container" class="clearfix">
    <div id="team-left"><span class="activity-title">Meet the team</span><br />
      <img src="../images/team-members-khklhll-vann.png" class="image-center" alt="khklhll AS Team Members" /></div>
    <div id="team-right">
      <p><b>Moou</b> - <span class="team-function">Founder and Chief Executing Officer</span></p>
      <p>25 years’ exptry.</p>
      <br />
      <p><b>Ond</b> - <span class="team-function">Adviser and Board Member</span></p>
      <p>Economistantile sector.</p>
      <br />
      <p><b>Hen</b> - <span class="team-function">Adviser and Board Member</span></p>
      <p>Bacheojects.</p>
      <br />
      <p><b>Pede</b> - <span class="team-function">Landowners</span></p>
      <p>Peter an terrain.</p>
      <br>
      <p><b>Babou</b> - <span class="team-function">Financial Advisor</span></p>
      <p>MBA fro a Six Sigma black belt.</p>
      <br />
      <p><b>Heleck </b> - <span class="team-function">Representative in Germany</span></p>
      <p>Several design.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--END page3-->
<div id="source">
  <div id="source-container">
    <div id="source-region" class="textzone">
      <p><span class="activity-title">Interacting ure</span></p>
      <img src="../images/khklhll-map.png" style="float:right; margin-left:15px;" alt="fzeez - Internature">
      <p>fzeez i.</p>
      <p>The m lakes.</p>
      <p>fzeez is agual.</p>
      <p>The Eim.</p>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div id="source-oursource" class="textzone">
      <p><span class="activity-title">Pure, rce</span></p>
      <p>Our minerillage of fzeez.</p>
      <p>The wiates.</p>
      <p>The w8.</p>
      <br>
      <img src="../images/khklhll-water-properties-fr.png" alt="khklhll Water rties" title="khklhll Waterties" /> </div>
    <div class="source-title-box"><span class="activity-title"><a href="#" data-region="source-region">The region</a></span></div>
    <div class="source-title-box"><span class="activity-title"><a href="#" data-region="source-oursource">The source</a></span></div>
    <img src="../images/clickhere.png"> </div>
  ​ </div>
<!--END page4-->
<div id="medias">
  <div id="medias-container">
    <div id="medias-title-box"><span class="activity-title">PRESS &amp; MEDIAS</span><br />
    </div>
    <div id="medias-table-header">
      <div id="medias-table-header-type">TYPE</div>
      <div id="medias-table-header-desc">DESCRIPTION</div>
      <div id="medias-table-header-lang">LANGUAGE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="medias-table-content">
      <div class="medias-table-content-type"><img src="../images/article.png" alt="Article" title="Article" /></div>
      <div class="medias-table-content-desc"><a href="../resources/sna0418.pdf" target="_blank">Bli med Apr. 2012</a></div>
      <div class="medias-table-content-lang"><img src="../images/no.png" alt="Norway" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="medias-table-content">
      <div class="medias-table-content-type"><img src="../images/article.png" alt="Article" title="Article"/></div>
      <div class="medias-table-content-desc"><a href="../resources/tron0403.pdf" target="_blank">Visa 03 Apr. 2012</a></div>
      <div class="medias-table-content-lang"><img src="../images/no.png" alt="Norway" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="medias-table-content">
      <div class="medias-table-content-type"><img src="../images/article.png" alt="Article" title="Article"/></div>
      <div class="medias-table-content-desc"><a href="http://www.adre684431.ece" target="_blank">Sa.no Aug. 2011</a></div>
      <div class="medias-table-content-lang"><img src="../images/no.png" alt="Norway" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--END page5-->
<div id="contact-us">
  <div id="contact-box">
    <p><h2>khklhll AS</h2></p>
    <p>7760 fzeez | Norway</p>
    <p>+47 99 75</p>
    <a href="#inline" class="modalbox highlightit"><img src="../images/mail.png" alt="Send us an e-mail" /></a><br />
  </div>
</div>
<!--END page6-->
<div id="footer">
  <div id="social">
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.khklhllvann.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="106" data-show-faces="false" data-font="verdana"></div>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="msa">Tweet</a> 
    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script> 
  </div>
  <a href="../index.php?lang=fr"><img src="../images/fr.png" alt="Version Française" title="khklhll en version Française"/></a> <a href="../index.php?lang=no"><img src="../images/no.png" alt="khklhll på norsk" title="khklhll på norsk" /></a> <a href="../index.php?lang=de"><img src="../images/de.png" alt="Deutsch" /></a> <a href="../index.php?lang=en"><img src="../images/uk.png" alt="khklhll in English" title="khklhll in English" /></a> </div>

<!-- hidden inline form -->
<div id="inline">
  <h2>SEND US A MESSAGE</h2>
  <Br />
  <form id="contact" action="#" method="post" name="contact">
    <input id="name" class="txt" type="name" name="name" placeholder="Name"/>
    <br />
    <input id="email" class="txt" type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail address"/>
    <br />
    <textarea id="msg" class="txtarea" name="msg" placeholder="Type your message here..."></textarea>
    <button id="send">Send E-mail</button>
  </form>
  <br />
</div>
<script src="../js/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script> 
<script src="../js/jquery.nav.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nav').onePageNav();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is too vague and open-ended. How can we know what to do with the CSS without knowing what it's being used for? However, I did happen to notice that you specify two different `display` styles for `.clearfix`.

Comment: giving your html would also help...

Comment: Thanks - have added the html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed lot of duplicates for font inheritance

short-coded `#FFFFFF` to `#fff`

short-coded padding, margins

added support for Opera & IE10 on `background-size`

Fixed some Typo's

CSS:

```
html, body, #contact-us {height: 100%;}
body {font: 12px 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;font-weight: 400;color: #000;margin: 0 auto;padding: 0;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;}
/*.clearfix {display: inline-block;}*/
.clearfix {display: block;}
.clearfix:after {content: ".";display: block;height: 0;clear: both;visibility: hidden;}
* html .clearfix {height: 1%;zoom:1;}
p {color: #000;}
h1 {font-weight: 300;letter-spacing:1px;color: #0A4672;}
h2 {font-weight: 500;letter-spacing:1px;color: #467FD9;}
span.team-function {color: #467FD9;}
span.activity-title {font-size: 22px;font-weight: 300;letter-spacing:1px;text-transform:uppercase;color: #467FD9;}
p.activity-footnote {font-size: 10px;text-align: left;color: #000;}
/* Positionning the logo on top left side */
#logo {position: fixed;float: left;top: 20px;left: 2%;font-size: 28px;font-weight: 400;z-index:1000;}
/* End Logo */
/* Horizontal Menu, aligned on the right side */
#nav {right: 2%;list-style: none;position: fixed;top: 30px;z-index: 1000;}
#nav > li {display: inline-block;float: left;zoom: 1;margin: 0 5px;}
#nav a {font-size: 12px;font-weight: 600;letter-spacing: 1px;float: left;top: 30px;padding: 0 15px;display: inline-block;font-size: 11px;text-decoration: none;height: 24px;color: #666;line-height: 24px;text-align: center;-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);text-transform: uppercase;background: white;-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";filter: alpha(opacity=80);opacity: 0.8;}
#nav a:hover {background: #dedede;}
#nav .current a {background: #666;color: #ededed;}
/* End Menu */
/* Page Presentation */
#presentation {height: 1300px;background: #afc9ff;background: url(../images/bg-24.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;-webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-ms-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover;}
#presentation-container {width:810px;padding-top: 15%;margin: 0 auto;}
.presentation-highlights {text-align: justify;margin-top:20px;margin-right:7px;float:left;padding:10px;font-size: 12px;width: 230px;height:90px;-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=85)";filter: alpha(opacity=95);opacity: 0.85; /* For IE8 and earlier */border: 1px dotted #666;background: #fff;}
/* End Page presentation */
/* Page Equipe */
#team {height: 1300px;padding-top: 150px;background: #8aba56 url(../images/bg-23.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;-webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-ms-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover;}
#team-container {width:960px;background-color:#fff;-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=83)";filter: alpha(opacity=83);opacity: 0.83;margin: 0 auto;background: #fff;border: 1px dotted #666;}
#team-left {color:#000;padding:20px 0 0 20px;width: 20%;float: left;position: relative;}
#team-right {font-size: 12px;padding:24px 0 20px 25px;color:#000;width: 70%;float: left;position: relative;text-align:justify;}
.image-center {text-align: center;display: block;margin: 0 auto;padding-top: 30px -15px 0 0;}
/* Page Plan d'Activité */
#activity {height: 1300px;background: #8aba56;padding-top: 150px;background: url(../images/bg-22.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;-webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-ms-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover;}
#activity-container {width: 640px;font-size: 12px;text-align:justify;background-color: #fff;color:#000;padding:25px;margin: 0 auto;border: 1px dotted #666;background: #fff url(../images/norway-map.png) no-repeat right center;-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=93)";filter: alpha(opacity=93);opacity: 0.93;}
/* End Page Activity */
/* Page Source */
#source {height: 1300px;background: #8aba56;padding-top: 150px;background: url(../images/bg-28.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;-webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-ms-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover;}
#source-container {width: 800px;margin:0 auto;;-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=93)";filter: alpha(opacity=93);opacity: 0.93;}
.source-title-box {color: #000;background: #fff;width: 230px;position: relative;margin-top:10px;border: 1px dotted #666;}
.source-title-box a {color:#467FD9;display:block;text-decoration:none;padding: 15px;}
.source-title-box a:hover {background-color:#467FD9;color:#fff;}
#source-region, #source-oursource {font-size: 12px;text-align:justify;background: #fff;color: #000;padding:15px 20px 20px 20px;display:block;width: 510px;float: right;position: relative;border: 1px dotted #666;line-height:1px;}
#source-oursource {display:none;}
#source-oursource p {margin-bottom:5px;}
#source-region p {margin-bottom:5px;padding-right:10px;}
/* Page Medias */
#medias {height: 1300px;background: #8aba56;padding-top: 150px;background: url(../images/bg-18.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;-webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-ms-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover;}
#medias-container {width: 800px;margin: 0 auto;}
#medias-title-box {color: #000;background: #fff;padding: 15px;width: 200px;float: left;position: relative;border: 1px dotted #666;}
#medias-table-header {background: #fff;color: #000;width: 490px;float: right;position: relative;border: 1px dotted #666;}
#medias-table-header-type, #medias-table-header-desc, #medias-table-header-lang {font-size: 22px;font-weight: 200;padding: 15px;background: #fff;color: #000;width: 50px;float: left;position: relative;}
#medias-table-header-desc {width: 200px;}
#medias-table-header-lang {width: 85px;}
.medias-table-content {margin-top: 10px;background: #fff;color: #000;width: 490px;float: right;position: relative;border: 1px dotted #666;}
.medias-table-content-type, .medias-table-content-desc, .medias-table-content-lang {padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;background: #fff;text-align:center;color: #000;width: 50px;float: left;position: relative;}
.medias-table-content-desc {font-size: 14px;font-weight: 200;padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;width: 200px;text-align:left;vertical-align:middle;}
.medias-table-content-desc a {text-decoration:none;color:#000;vertical-align:middle;}
.medias-table-content-desc a:hover {color:#0A4672;text-decoration:underline;}
.medias-table-content-lang {width: 85px;}
/* end page medias */
/* Page Contact */
#contact-us {background: #8aba56;padding: 0;position: relative;background: url(../images/bg-26.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;-webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-ms-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover;}
#contact-box {text-align:center;font-size: 12px;width: 300px;height:120px;padding:15px;-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=85)";filter: alpha(opacity=95);opacity: 0.85;border: 1px dotted #666;background: #fff;position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;margin-top: -80px 0 0 -150px;}
#contact-box p {font-size: 12px;color: #000;letter-spacing:2px;margin-bottom:3px;}
#contact-box h2 {font-size: 22px;font-weight: 500;letter-spacing:2px;color: #467FD9;}
.highlightit img {filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=50);opacity: 1;}
.highlightit:hover img {filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=100);opacity: 0.7;}
/* Section Footer with social icons on the left and address and flags on the right */
#footer {position: fixed;bottom: 0;color: #333;left: 0;z-index: 999;width: 96%;text-align: right;padding: 30px 2%;vertical-align: bottom;}
#social {position: absolute;vertical-align: middle;left: 2%;color: #333;}
.txtcentered {width: 300px;height: 200px;position: absolute;left: 50%;top: 50%;margin: -100px 0 0 -150px;}
.fb_iframe_widget, iframe.twitter-share-button {display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;}
.languageselector {display: inline-block;height: 20px;line-height: 20px;}
/*contact form*/
#inline {display: none;width: 600px;}
.txt {display: inline-block;color: #676767;width: 420px;font-family: Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;margin-bottom: 10px;border: 1px dotted #ccc;padding: 5px 9px;font-size: 1.2em;line-height: 1.4em;}
.txtarea {display: block;-webkit-resize: none;-moz-resize: none;resize: none;color: #676767;font-family: Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;margin-bottom: 10px;width: 500px;height: 150px;border: 1px dotted #ccc;padding: 5px 9px;font-size: 1.2em;line-height: 1.4em;}
.txt:focus, .txtarea:focus {border-style: solid;border-color: #bababa;color: #444;}
input.error, textarea.error {border-color: #973d3d;border-style: solid;background: #f0bebe;color: #a35959;}
input.error:focus, textarea.error:focus {border-color: #973d3d;color: #a35959;}
#send {color: #dee5f0;display: block;cursor: pointer;padding: 5px 11px;font-size: 1.2em;border: solid 1px #224983;border-radius: 5px;background: #1e4c99;background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#2f52b7), to(#0e3a7d));background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2f52b7, #0e3a7d);background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2f52b7, #0e3a7d);background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2f52b7, #0e3a7d);background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2f52b7, #0e3a7d);background: linear-gradient(top, #2f52b7, #0e3a7d);filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#2f52b7', endColorstr='#0e3a7d');}
#send:hover {background: #183d80;background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#284f9d), to(#0c2b6b));background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #284f9d, #0c2b6b);background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #284f9d, #0c2b6b);background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #284f9d, #0c2b6b);background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #284f9d, #0c2b6b);background: linear-gradient(top, #284f9d, #0c2b6b);filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#284f9d', endColorstr='#0c2b6b');}
#send:active {color: #8c9dc0;background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0e387d), to(#2f55b7));background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0e387d, #2f55b7);background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0e387d, #2f55b7);background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0e387d, #2f55b7);background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0e387d, #2f55b7);background: linear-gradient(top, #0e387d, #2f55b7);filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0e387d', endColorstr='#2f55b7');}
```

Improve HTML:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content=".">
<link href="../css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="../js/scripts.js" /></script>
```